# How do I fully reset DD-WRT?

Tags: wireless-router, dd-wrt

I have a Linksys WRT54GS wireless router flashed with DD-WRT, and I forgot my username and password for it. Thus, I am unable to reset the password from the web interface.

Without access to the web interface, how can I fully reset everything?

Answer (score 9):

To fully reset a router flashed with DD-WRT, perform a [30-30-30 reset](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Hard_reset_or_30/30/30):

> The following procedure will clear out the NVRAM and set dd-wrt back to default values:
>
> - With the unit powered on, press and hold the reset button on back of unit for 30 seconds.
> - Without releasing the reset button, unplug the unit and hold reset for another 30 seconds.
> - Plug the unit back in STILL holding the reset button a final 30 seconds (please note that this step can put Asus devices into recovery mode)

After you do this, you'll need to log in with the default username ("root") and password ("admin").

Comment: ARM based devices can be bricked by 30/30/30 so use with care. Also see: https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Hard_reset_or_30/30/30

Answer (score 0):

Turn the device on, and then hold the **Factory Reset** button for 30 seconds. After you release, it should be reset to the default username and password.